# Sonar Issue "Return values should not be ignored when they contain the operation status code" getting for Java code

Tags: java, file, sonarqube

I am getting the Sonar Issue "Return values should not be ignored when they contain the operation status code" for below line of code.

```
 directory.delete();
```

Do something with the "boolean" value returned by "delete()" error I am getting.
I tried to add condition like

```
if(!directory.delete()){
            logger.error("failed to delete");
        }
```

Sonar issue is getting fixed but it is affecting for code, please let me know, how to fix the issue.

Comment: what do you mean "it is affecting for code"? What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can use logger without side-effect for the code, for instance like that:

```
var retVal = directory.delete();
logger.info("entity " + reVal + " was deleted");
```

Comment: that logging would make no sense at all

Comment: that logging solves sonar code smeel. which author wants to suppress without the influence to the code, moreover it makes sence for getting information about deleted entity

Comment: the delete method returns a boolean. Could you please explain the information you would extract from "entity false was deleted"?

Comment: Read the problem which the author solves, He wants to hide sonar issue about usage the return value in the method. The easiest way to get rid of that is usage logging, it is not about practical helpfulness it is about how he can win sonar issue, there are a lot of possible ways. By the way, why do you think that the method returns boolean? Do you see his code?

Comment: yes, I do, did you not? It's in the question. if(!directory.delete()) besides, the delete method of the File class is pretty well known. "it is about how he can win sonar issue", he could just delete all the code as well, the sonar issues would be resolved. But, just because it resolves a sonar issue, doesn't mean it's a good approach

Comment: Why did I not see your perfect solution here?

Comment: ah ... I haven't posted an answer, hence I'm not allowed to point out the flaws in yours. didn't know SO worked like that, will consider it from now on